# how can I clean my map to return Map<String, String> Instead Map<String? , String?> In kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I am kinda new using kotlin and I was wondering if I can do something like this.

I have a list with objects of type `Person`,

`Person` has properties like `name, id` but can be null.

So I made something like this:

```
return persons.filter {
    it.name != null && it.id != null
  }.map {
    it.id to it.name
  }.toMap()
```

I personally dont see the error but the compiler keeps telling me I should return a map of not nulls.

Is there any way I can do it using filter and map using lambdas functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`mapNotNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-not-null.html) to combine `filter` and `map`:

```
persons.mapNotNull { 
    val id = it.id
    val name = it.name
    if (id != null && name != null) Pair(id, name) else null
}.toMap()
```

Pulling `id` and `name` into local variables should make sure they'll get inferred as not-null in `Pair(id, name)` but may not be necessary.

The reason your approach doesn't work is that `persons.filter { ... }` just returns `List<Person>`, there's no way to say "list of `Person`s with non-null `name` and `id`" or to represent it internally in the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

btw, you can even get rid of `if` in `mapNotNull`:

```
persons.mapNotNull {
    val id = it.id ?: return@mapNotNull null
    val name = it.name ?: return@mapNotNull null
    id to name
}.toMap()
```

Answer (score 2):

May be you can simply change

```
.map {
    it.id to it.name
}
```

into

```
.map {
    it.id!! to it.name!!
}
```

The suffix `!!` operator converts `String?` into `String`, throwing exception if the value with type `String?` is `null`, which in our case can't be true, due to the previously applied filter.
Use of `!!` should be limited to cases where you take responsibility of explicitly asserting that value can't be null: you're saying to the compiler that values are `String` even if the type is `String?` - and should be imho used with caution.
Compiler can't infer the type domain restriction from `String?` to `String` from the predicate passed to `filter`, but you can, so I think `!!` usage can be a valuable approach...

Comment: I prefer the `mapNotNull` approach for 2 reasons: 1. doesn't create an unnecessary intermediate list (unless you work with `Sequence`, in which case neither will `filter`+`map`); 2. less potential to break on future changes.